# Exclude third_party from clang-tidy checks

Tags: c++, clang, clang-static-analyzer, clang-tidy

I'm trying to run `clang-tidy` on a big project with a lot of files that include third party libraries:

```cpp
#include "third_party/..."
```

And thus I receive a lot of errors corresponding to these third party libraries.
Adding `NOLINT` to each include is not an option since the project is large (and it seems that it doesn't work).

I tried to use `-header-filter`, but I still receive errors from third party libraries.

```sh
clang-tidy -header-filter='-third_party' "${SOURCE_FILES[@]}"
```

Is it possible to exclude `third_party/*` from checks?

Answer (score 3):

You should flag these headers as system headers.

You can do this via

```
#pragma clang system_header
```

These headers will get ignored by clang-tidy and will produce no warnings.

Comment: Is it the only way? Because I don't own the library that is being downloaded to the `third_party/`.